# How to inject inline script when Content Security Policy is preventing it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, inline-scripting

I'm using `Chrome Extension ReactJS` which I'd like to insert this in `popup.html`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ringcentral-c2d@1.0.0/build/index.js"></script>
<script>
  window.clickToDialInject = new RingCentralC2D();
  window.clickToDialInject.on(
    RingCentralC2D.events.call,
    function (phoneNumber) {
      console.log('Click To Dial:', phoneNumber);
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        const currentTabId = tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, { clickToCall: phoneNumber });
      });
      // alert('Click To Dial:' + phoneNumber);
    }
  );
  window.clickToDialInject.on(
    RingCentralC2D.events.text,
    function (phoneNumber) {
      console.log('Click To SMS:', phoneNumber);
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        const currentTabId = tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, { clickToSMS: phoneNumber });
      });
      // alert('Click To SMS:' + phoneNumber);
    }
  );
</script>
```

I am having this error in console. I already tried the meta tag but I cant figure out what directive should I use.

[image]

Right now, it only works if I directly paste the script from `https://unpkg.com/ringcentral-c2d@1.0.0/build/index.js` inside the `popup.jsx`, but its not appropriate way.

How could I overcome this?

Comment: Download the file into extension directory and load it just like any other script in your extension. Don't load scripts from network into the highly privileged environment of an extension as any remote URL may be spoofed (even on https) or become unavailable offline.

Comment: Have you tried setting a Content-Security-Policy script-src? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src